# python number of button clicks are incrementing on every button press

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make program that increments the number of clicks by saving on a `Text` 
for example if I press a button  many times it prints that number of times I pressed correctly but my problem is if  I press onother button  it starts it's incrementing from the number of clicks of the first one not from zero

so please how I can make it start from zero if press other button

```
bttn_clicks=0
button_dict = {}


def showqado():
     global button,data2
     data2 = readqado()
     for index, dat in enumerate(data2):
        button = ttk.Button(master, text=dat[0],command=lambda dat=dat: update_count(dat))
        button.grid(row=index+1, column=1,pady=0,padx=0)
        button_dict[dat] = button


def update_count(x):
     global bttn_clicks,my_text,price
     my_text=StringVar()
     for name in data2:
         my_text = button_dict[x].cget('text')
     bttn_clicks += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the problem is that `bttn_clicks` increases with every button press?

This is because every button "`update_count`" function is referring to the `global bttn_clicks` variable.

You probably want a version of this variable stored on each button instead.

---

This is a very simplified version of what your code is doing:

```
count = 0

def update_count():
    global count
    count += 1

Button1 = update_count
Button2 = update_count
Button1()
Button1()
Button2()

count
#>>3
```

You can see that no matter where you call the "update_count" function, there is *only one `count`* going on.

Instead, you want multiple. One way of doing that is through classes. For instance, you could attach a Counter class like the below to each button and call each Button's counter separately.

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self): #sets count to zero when first initialized
        self.count = 0
    def increase(self):
        self.count += 1 #function to increase the count by one

counter = Counter() #first instance
counter.increase()
counter.increase()

counter2 = Counter() #second instance
counter2.increase()

counter.count #first instance "count"
#>>2
counter2.count #second instance "count"
#>>1
```

Comment: @mohamedabdallah I'm afraid this is the best I can do at the moment, unless you just need me to explain some aspect of the code I provided.